# I BORROWED MONEY FROM MY RICH BROTHER BUT THE SCAMMER ON THE INTERNET DID A FRAUD.. DO I PAY BACK AS IT WAS A FRAUD?

Tags: debt

I lost money and filed a fraud case as I was scammed on a website. The money is so much that I am worried I cannot payback brother it will take me 7 years. My brother is rich but he wants the money, I have lost nearly all my wealth and live on 2 pounds per day after paying all the necessary bills.

Answer (score 0):

I am very sad to hear your situation. May Allah ease your problems. Brother just make your brother cool down and tell him your situation. He is your brother he will truly forgive you. You can return his money when you are stable enough

Answer (score 0):

In surah Baqara, it says:

If the debtor is in a difficulty grant him time till it is easy for him to repay. But if ye remit it by way of charity, that is best for you if ye only knew. (2:280).

So if he follows the Quran he should give you time to pay it.

I also recall a hadith where a man is asked in the grave by an angel, "what good deeds did you do in your life" the man replies "I let some one off (i.e. dismissed) an amount he owed me" the angel will reply you are thus also dismissed (from punishment of the grave).

Comment: Well, my Brother knew it was a FRAUD. The person who did this to me ran away and cannot be found. The question is with good intention was made on our part but if it's fraud what is the ruling now?